# C++ Templated Subject Observer Inheritance/Cast Conflict

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, shared-ptr

I am using the example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3267/Implementing-a-Subject-Observer-pattern-with-templ to implement a templated subject/observer pattern.  However, I am getting annoying compile errors looking like inheritance isn't working, or an odd cast.  Any help would be great.  At the bottom of the post is the line causing the issue.

The error

```
FooManager.h: In member function
    'ReturnEnum FooManager::AddBar(BarPtr)':

Foo.h:150: error: no matching function for call to
    'Bar::attach(FooManagerPtr)'

Subject.h:23: note: candidates are: 
    void Subject<T>::attach(Observer<T>) [with T = boost::shared_ptr<Bar>]
```

The Code

types.h

```
class Bar;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Bar> BarPtr;

class FooManager;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<FooManager> FooManagerPtr;
```

Observer.h

```
#include "types.h"
template <class T>
class Observer
{
    public:
        Observer(){}
        virtual ~Observer() {}
        virtual void update(T subject) = 0;
};
```

Subject.h

```
#include "types.h"
template <class T>
class Subject
{
    private:
        vector< Observer<T> > m_observers;

    public:
        Subject() {}
        virtual ~Subject() {}
        void attach(Observer<T> observer)
        {
            m_observers.push_back(observer);
        }

        void notify()
        {
            for(vector< Observer<T> >::iterator it = m_observers.begin(); it != m_observers.end(); ++it)
            {
                (*it)->update(static_cast<T>(this));
            }
        }
};
```

Bar.h

```
#include "types.h"
class Bar             : public Subject<BarPtr>
{
};
```

FooManager.h

```
#include "types.h"
class FooManager                : public Observer<BarPtr>
{
    public:
        ReturnEnum AddBar(BarPtr pBar)
        {
            pBar->attach( FooManagerPtr(this, boost_null_deleter()) );
        }
};
```

Comment: You're trying to send a `boost::shared_ptr` to this function: `void attach(Observer<T> observer)`, because `FooManagerPtr` is a `boost::shared_ptr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve, you could try to change (warning, untested code!):

```
    void attach(Observer<T> observer)
    {
        m_observers.push_back(observer);
    }
```

to

```
    void attach(boost::shared_ptr<Observer<T>> observer)
    {
        m_observers.push_back(observer);
    }
```

and

```
vector< Observer<T> > m_observers;
```

to

```
vector< boost::shared_ptr<Observer<T> > > m_observers;
```

Comment: Maybe you need some other modifications to your code. Let me know if you manage to get it working, but, you should first try to understand what `boost::shared_ptr` does.

Answer (score 1):

`pBar` points to `Bar` instance, so `attach()` expects `Observer<BarPtr>`, while you pass `shared_ptr<Observer<BarPtr> >`.

(By the way, if you already use boost, wouldn't you be better off with Boost.Signals2?)

Comment: Never knew about it.  I may give that a shot since it looks fairly easy, especially for boost.

Comment: @pyInTheSky it is very easy to use, thread-safe, and allows you to easily track observers by means of weak_ptr<observer>.

Comment: Best answer goes to Mihai for having the actual solution to the problem, though I will most likely use the signals as it looks to be an even cleaner implementation, so +1 and thanks you